# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module next.config.js firebase pwa

Tags: firebase, import, next.js, config, progressive-web-apps

After update node version I get this error in next.config.js:

```
import { app } from './firebase';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

The same when I tried to use next/dynamic and require.

But when I delete import for app I have this:

```
const firestore = app.firestore();
                    ^ 
ReferenceError: app is not defined
```

I use next-pwa, CNA and I try to turn on enableIndexedDbPersistence and cacheSizeBytes for Firebase.
Before update node wersion, I didn't have import and it was ok. Now isn't wrong.
In another project I use yarn and this project npm.

My next config:

```
    /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
  
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");
import('firebase/firestore').then(() => {
  const firestore = app.firestore();
  // Use Cloud Firestore ...
  firestore().settings({
    cacheSizeBytes: 400
  });
  firestore.enableIndexedDbPersistence()
  .catch((e) => {
    if (e.code === 'failed-precondition') {
      console.error(e.code)
    } else if (e.code === 'unimplemented') {
      console.error(e.code)
    }
  });
});

module.exports = withPWA({
  reactStrictMode: true,
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'jp', 'pl'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
  images: {
    deviceSizes: [280, 320, 375, 425, 768, 1024, 1200, 1440, 2560],
    loader: 'default',
    domains: ['firebasestorage.googleapis.com', 's.yimg.com'],
    formats: ['image/avif', 'image/webp'],
  },
  pwa: {
    dest: "public",
    register: true,
    skipWaiting: true,
  },
});
```

My firebase.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY}`,
  authDomain: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN}`,
  projectId: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJ_ID}`,
  storageBucket: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET}`,
  messagingSenderId: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SENDER_ID}`,
  appId: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID}`
};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of the errors in my server console by using the older version [@next-auth/firebase-adapter@1.0.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@next-auth/firebase-adapter/v/1.0.1)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32922252)